# How to fit a image into a div without cutting or disturbing its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css

```
.container {
    background-color: #ffd2d3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("https://www.pexels.com/photo/beautiful-view-of-moraine-lake-2662116/");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I tried using above code but it does not fit entirely and using "background-size: cover;", cuts the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this help you to fix the problem:

```css
.container {
    background-color: #ffd2d3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2662116/pexels-photo-2662116.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the img css to make that work.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
    object-fit:cover;
}
```